# Emberjs adding `.property()` in a function attribute of a controller/route

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to do the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249900/adding-class-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-bind-attr/25250826#25250826)

**My real question is why did he have to add `.property()` at the end of the function in the `errorClass` attribute? And can someone please point me to a documentation on how this work?**

when I don't include the `.property()`, a stringed function of the attribute is placed as value in my template.

**Handlebar:**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show {{loginActiveClass}}" id="login" role="tabpanel">
```

**Expectation:**

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#login" role="tab" class="nav-link active">
```

**What happens when I discard the `.property()`:**

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#login" role="tab" class="nav-link function loginActiveClass() {
  return this.get('page') === 'login' ? 'active' : '';
}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `{{att}}` in your hbs you access the value of the component's or controller's attribute/property named `att`.

By your description, your attribute `loginActiveClass` has a value of type `function`. This is what you get in your handlebars. Since the position where you use it only admits string values, you get the `toString()` representation of your value, which for a function is the function's code as string.

You cannot trigger actual evaluation of the function code by simply accessing it with `{{att}}` in your .hbs.

Adding `.property()` at the end gives you a *computed property* that does indeed evaluate the function and returns the evaluation result to the "caller". (Note that the preferred syntax for computed properties in Ember has changed a while ago to [something more explicit](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty). I recommend using eslint and [eslint-plugin-ember](https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember) to let your IDE or ember's cli inform you about best practices when appropriate.)

Also, in your specific example, the "logic" of the function is easily integrated into the hbs:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show {{if (eq page 'login') 'active'}}" id="login" role="tabpanel">
```

Comment: Your link isn't working.. so I can do `computedProperty: Ember.computed(function(){ return this.get('...') === '...'})`. Why do I see some example providing string parameters before the function? I tried doing this but its working even if I do not supply the '...' string before the function in the `Ember.computed` function.

Comment: @RichardDomingo Fixed the link, sorry about that. The string**s** right after `.computed(` enumerate the properties the computed property depends on - when any of their values change the function is evaluated anew. Presumably you are not changing the value of `page` while viewing the same rendered template and hence it *looks as if it is working* in your case, but try to change the value of `page` using Ember inspector & the browser console and you will see that without named dependent properties, the function is evaluated only once.